# Algorithm progress callback

Tags: c#, wpf, callback

I have to implement very complex algorithm with a lot of iterations, matrix operations etc. There are two major loops for Fourier series approximation. I would like to know what is the best approach to implement progress callback. I na future I would like to use this algorithm in WPF app and I would like to implement progress bar. How to prepare algorithm to make progress bar implementaion easy in a future?

I am thinking about something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Progres...  ");
    Alg((i) => UpdateProgress(i));            
}

public static void UpdateProgress(int iteration)
{
    string anim = @"|/-\-";            
    Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 1, Console.CursorTop);
    Console.Write(anim[iteration%5]);                        
}

public static void Alg(Action<int> progressCallback)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        progressCallback(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Progress: Operations Completed / Operations To Go

Comment: This is clear. But I am asking for something else. What to use delegate, Func or what as a parameter of algorithm. What will be the best option here?

Comment: You should be able to implement the algorithm running on a separate thread and updating the UI with `BackgroundWorker` and its `ProgressChanged` event. Take a look at this link for some more information: http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/03/wpf-multithreading-using-the-backgroundworker-and-reporting-the-progress-to-the-ui/.

Comment: If this solves your issue or You would like some help with the code, let me know, so I'll post it as an answer and add more information, if needed.

Comment: I like your comment because you have pointed out an important thing - do not freez UI. I think I will stay with my idea of collback as Action in my opinion it is loosely coupled. For threading I am using TPL as it does more for me than BackgroundWorker.

Comment: Is that `Thread.Sleep(50)` just there to simulate some work?  Cause if that's a real part of the code, you might consider using a Timer instead...

Comment: @cHao: just to simulate. And Alg is not real life algorithm as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer to use `TPL`, why not stick with it?
You can use 'IProgress' http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/hh193692.aspx .

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Progres...  ");

        Progress<int> progress = new Progress<int>();

        var task = Alg(progress);            

        progress.ProgressChanged += (s, i) => { UpdateProgress(i); };

        task.Start();
        task.Wait();
    }

    public static void UpdateProgress(int iteration)
    {
        string anim = @"|/-\-";
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 1, Console.CursorTop);
        Console.Write(anim[iteration % anim.Count()]);
    }

    public static Task Alg(IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        Task t = new Task
        (
            () =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(50);
                    ((IProgress<int>)progress).Report(i);
                }
            }
        );
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not know `Progress<T>`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need object which implements interface [INotifyPropertChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/BR209899). The property of this object that represents progress state will be bound to XAML element that visualize that progress state (Progressbar). In your algorithm you need just set this property to appropriate value. Your algorithm can get this object as parameter. Or you can set this property in delegate which is supplied to you algorithm. WPF takes care about delivering change of property to UI thread if you are working with multiple threads.