# C# .NET 4 Can Task provides notifications on UI thread?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

I am using Task class in my app. This is NOT WPF application! The question is are there any possibilities of calling function from Task body on UI thread, like this:

```
var task = new Task(() => DoSmth(1));
task.Start();

public void DoSmth(int arg)
    {
        //smth
        CallNotifFuncOnUIThread(() => Notify(1));
        //smth ELSE
        CallNotifFuncOnUIThread(() => Notify(2));//notify AGAIN
        //smth ELSE
    }

public void Notify(int arg)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = arg;
    }
```

Or maybe there are other solutions of this problem? I know about BackgroundWorker class, but what about Tasks?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971686

Comment: Is it WPF? If so, use a [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx), namely the `Application.Current.Dispatcher` which will give you the UI dispatcher. That's of course if you want to update the UI somewhere in the middle of the background processing, if you just want to update it at the very end, use the appropriate scheduler context in the continuation.

Comment: Here is answer for similiar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327717/algorithm-progress-callback/15661639#15661639 use TPL INotify interface

Answer (score 1):

You can always call other methods inside your DoSth()

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(...);
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...);
```

You can also user `Task.ContinueWith(...)` to do sth after the task is finished processing ...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a task you can start it on the gui thread by providing the correct scheduler:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomethingOnGUI(), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

With windows Form and progressBar1 component on ityou can use TPL `IProgress` interface for `Task`.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Progress<int> progress = new Progress<int>();
        var task = Alg(progress);
        progress.ProgressChanged += (s, i) => { UpdateProgress(i); };
        task.Start();
    }

    public void Notify(int arg)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = arg;
    }

    public static Task Alg(IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        Task t = new Task
        (
            () =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    ((IProgress<int>)progress).Report(i);
                }
            }
        );
        return t;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

UI is usually STA see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680112(v=vs.85).aspx

so in order to do something from none UI thread in the UI you need to inject somehow the msg into the thread
see for example htis winform example:

http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/articles/126345.aspx

watever UI you are using you will need a similar system.